# Cannot set proper scope for Google Docs API

Tags: google-api, google-docs

I have a problem with my Google oAuth authorisation. When I set scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` it works properly, but when I set scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` I cannot authorise (Signing in by Google in this application is temporarily disabled
We have not yet verified this app for Google Sign In.).

I have no idea why readonly scope is a problem to authorise to Google by oAuth.

Comment: Sounds like you have been though the verification process already with one scope and have changed the scopes meaning that you need to submit the verification process again.

Answer (score 0):

If is a new scope for your OAuth Consent screen then you will have to submit a new verification process. Every time a scope is added, removed, or changed you will have to submit a new verification process.

Check https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en for more information. I would suggest you to contact G Suite API support team, just create a case from your Admin Console and request to speak with them, if you need to start or you are in the process of being verified they can assist you to speed up the process only if you started the process several days ago.